# "Complex" Typescript Conditional Generic Types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

## Context

I'm trying to strongly type a UI library's Select component's `onChange`.

For context their `onChange` is typed as:

```
  onChange?: (...args: any[]) => void;
```

The caveat is, they support an additional prop/parameter named `valueKey`, which is used when the options you pass are an object, `valueKey` tells the library how to access the object to pull the value out.

```
  valueKey?:
    | string
    | { key: string; reduce?: boolean }
    | ((...args: any[]) => string);
```

I'm mostly concerned with `{ key: string; reduce?: boolean }`.

The `reduce` field if true, modifies the value passed to `onChange`.

Contrived Example:

```
// Without `reduce`
<Select
  options={[{ label: 'Hello', value: 'hello' }]}
  labelKey="label"
  valueKey={{ key: 'value' }}
  onChange={(option) => // option is { label: 'Hello', value: 'hello' }
    ...
/>

// ...

// With reduce
<Select
  options={[{ label: 'Hello', value: 'hello' }]}
  labelKey="label"
  valueKey={{ key: 'value', reduce: true }}
  onChange={(option) => // option is 'hello'
    ...
/>
```

## Attempt

Given the above, here is a [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?experimentalDecorators=false&emitDecoratorMetadata=false&target=2#code/PTAEDkHsBcFMC5QFEA2sC2sB21QGcALSAVxQBNQAjWUAKQGUANAOlQ22gBorjdoCAhrjKRYeLAHJceWBlDRIVGnmIAHVZABOcCgVibYAKGgBPVTQDyq6AEtIWPKAC8oABR5omm1gDmoAD6gWMTo1JoBVJCQaAJYEZCUAFawAMa4gWyYOACUANoAuobGZjQAagIoxLAA0rAmADzVoLAAHnBYZI4eXr4AfM6GoBHd3j6DEa6uzNMCmj54iLEmBdnO-SO+2eOBAN6gANZ1iNUA3KAGZMQpsAD8iJRRMXEAvidFpuag5ZWwFgBm3yqtQa4wszTa2E6oCstnseE44yarXaUI2PgRQ1KSIhHUcgJqdUavUM-RcWPBKMce0OJmOZwuV1u90esFioGe4xuX2quQkDOuEnyFMhjk8VU50NywVC+iFyJFoAASqktGR6mjuEtiUMuRYpSEwvlcljeTTBYUhogJFgYKA2QlkmkJOMrfwbHgALSUTSxFIEZ2W0BSAjuj0wPSaL0+rB+iRvYqfADCxA8kEw4RcO3GAH1sx9sAJMFbk6n0xIMaAbGREGi3kMfJoSKoAJLVoIG-R1oKFhD4TyjN6vIopOHSWBoNIwuwORAlhTpgrOUC5cZZoZDXP5rA94sp+f6cvjIZVq0ARgATABmAAsAFZD+vQA2m63EFeL5fTxWhtui0G52m+gAIIBuyhj5PG+agAAKmI0CNHUwq4n2PQ+KSXwVFU-z4sC9T5pAfz4OOqTQFOcLcMC3DUkcoCUecsCXNciBijQzy9G8UGwR455Llx8ESM+aithIxKGCODi4H8cQuPUYLyshZEOBRSGov2vhLhIImuNkiBrqA9iJoIvi9q4ABuFSIPi2GYQSDQWBR3A4YS1S9L0qxOP0pmQFWhjPGsoB6QY0DEJocR7AZRk+CZ5koO5-Q7M8Q7PEAA) to showcase the attempt, or code:

```
// Note: Element should be JSX.Element, but that doesn't seem to be supported here
type Options = (string | number | boolean | object | Element)[]

type ValueKey<K extends string> =
  | string
  | ((...args: any[]) => string)
  | { key: K; reduce?: boolean };

type ValueOfValueKey<
  O extends Options,
  K extends string,
  VK extends ValueKey<K>
> = VK extends { key: K; reduce?: boolean }
  ? VK['reduce'] extends true
  ? O[number] extends Record<string, any>
  ? O[number][VK['key']]
  : 'not an object'
  : 'this-branch'
  : 'this-other-branch';

type Customer = {
  __typename: 'Customer',
  id: string;
  groupId: number;
  name: string;
};

const selectOptions: Customer[] = [
  {
    __typename: 'Customer',
    id: '12345',
    groupId: 231231,
    name: 'CustomerA'
  }
];

type Test<Key extends string> = ValueOfValueKey<typeof selectOptions, Key, { key: Key, reduce: true }>;
type Test2 = Test<'groupId'>

const fn = <O extends Options, K extends string = ''>(): {
  onChange: (val: ValueOfValueKey<O, K, ValueKey<K>>) => void
} => {
  return { onChange: (val) => {}};
}
```

`Test2` is properly reduced down to `number` in this example, good!

However, in the simple definition of `fn`, `onChange` is `(val: "this-other-branch" | "this-branch") => void`

But i'd like it to be `number` in this case and I'm not sure where things are going wrong with this definition.

## Use Case Example

```
const MyForm = () => {
  const [selectedCustomer, setSelectedCustomer] = useState<null | string>(null);

  return (
    <form>
      {/* Without reduce */}
      <Select
        options={selectOptions}
        labelKey="label"
        valueKey={{ key: 'id' }}
        onChange={(option) => {
          // Because an option is of type `any`, without prior knowledge
          // a developer needs to probably console log out `option` to see here
          // that `option` would be of type: `Customer`
          // otherwise possible crash
          setSelectedCustomer(option);
        }}
      />

      {/* With reduce */}
      <Select
        options={selectOptions}
        labelKey="label"
        valueKey={{ key: 'id', reduce: true }}
        onChange={(option) => {
          // Because an option is of type `any`, without prior knowledge
          // a developer needs to probably console log out `option` to see here
          // that `option` would be of type `string` because of `Customer['id']
          // otherwise possible crash
          setSelectedCustomer(option);
        }}
      />
    </form>
  );
};
```

In general, I'm trying to provide a helpful/better DX.

Comment: I'm getting lost in your playground example with those weird string literals.  What is `"this-other-branch"` and `"this-branch"` supposed to be doing?  I wish I understood the use case from your "context" section more so I could try to make my own solution instead of debugging your attempt.  Actually, backing up... are you looking for someone to debug your code or suggest a solution?  If it's the former then could you write out some input/output use cases?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the post to include some use-cases.

As for debugging or a solution, a bit of both.

Comment: As for the string literals, they exist just to clarify which branch the conditional type is going into, realistically you can replace the string literals with `O[number]` because that's what it would be in practice

Comment: "a bit of both" doesn't really help focus.  If you got two answers; one which explained perfectly what was wrong with your code but didn't fix it, and one which perfectly implemented a solution without involving your attempt at all, which one, if either, would be acceptable to you?

Comment: In that case, a solution. I'd like to understand what's going wrong here to better understand TypeScript while providing a way forward with my specific use-case.

Comment: Then [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKRoMm) would be the approach I'd pursue instead of tying myself in conditional type inference knots.  If that works for you I'd be happy to write up an answer; if not and there's a use case it doesn't match, please let me know what it is (and [edit] the question with those use cases).  If you really want someone to debug and untangle your attempt it might have to be someone else and not me.  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: I'm not too sure how well the overloads can fit into the scheme of things codebase wise, but it gives me enough to work off of. It's certainly easier to reason about.

I'd accept it as an answer, could you maybe include why you prefer this approach over as you say, "conditional type inference knots". 

To restate, the overloads are definitely more readable, but in terms of the "power" of conditional types why would you avoid it?

Use case added, btw

Comment: Could you help me out with your use cases? I'm trying to verify them with [the playground](https://tsplay.dev/wjQOYW) but seeing weirdness (is `"label"` a key of `Customer`? .  If you can set it up so that dropping into a standalone IDE demonstrates your issue without extraneous errors it's a lot easier for me to help.

Comment: The problem is that it's hard for the compiler to infer generic type parameters `T` and `U` from a value of `F<T, U>` if `F` is some arbitrary type built out of conditional types.  Inference is essentially *reversing* type evaluation.  It's easy to go from `T` and `U` to `F<T, U>` but it could be hard or impossible to go from `F<T, U>` to `T` and `U`.  Need I explain why? You are expecting the compiler to infer `O` and `K` from `ValueOfValueKey<O, K, ValueKey<K>>`.

Comment: And the only way for that to happen is if `ValueOfValueKey` and `ValueKey` were incredibly simple and transparent.  But they're not.  I could spend a long time trying to pick apart exactly where it fails, but that is very tedious.  I'm hoping I can just say "don't try to infer `T` from `F<T>` unless `F` is very simple and transparent" and move on with the overload solution.

Comment: I was out, so i can work on putting together a more coherent use case now, otherwise your explanation is enough and makes sense. You can put that as an answer if you want and I'll mark it, appreciate the explanation

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I stumbled upon the solution, thanks to the help of jcalz.

The main issue is that the generic in itself, *works*, but in my case, I wasn't also declaring the generics on the function itself, which the function overloads helped give me that hint.

The final solution ends up looking something like (irrelevant code parts taken out):

```
type Options = (string | number | boolean | object | JSX.Element)[]

type ValueKey<K extends string> =
  | K
  | ((...args: any[]) => string)
  | { key: K; reduce?: boolean };

type ValueOfValueKey<
  O extends Options,
  K extends string,
  VK extends ValueKey<K>
> = VK extends {
  key: K;
  reduce?: boolean;
}
  ? VK['reduce'] extends true
    ? O[number] extends Record<string, any>
      ? O[number][VK['key']]
      : O[number]
    : O[number]
  : O[number];

type FormSelectInputProps<
  FormValues extends FieldValues,
  Opts extends Options,
  K extends string,
  VK extends ValueKey<K>
> = Omit<
  SelectProps, // Props provided by the UI Library
  'ref' | 'name' | 'defaultValue' | 'onChange' | 'valueKey' | 'options'
> &
    valueKey?: VK;
    options: Opts;

    onChange?: (value: ValueOfValueKey<Opts, K, VK>) => void;
  };

export const FormSelectInput = <
  FormValues extends FieldValues, // Irrelevant, but this is a react-hook-form
                                  // FieldValues
  Opts extends Options, // <-- I was not declaring this before
  K extends string, // <-- I was not declaring this before
  VK extends ValueKey<K> // <-- I was not declaring this before
>({
   ...props
}: FormSelectInputProps<FormValues, Opts, K, VK>): JSX.Element => {
```

That's why in my examples

```
type Test<Key extends string> = ValueOfValueKey<typeof selectOptions, Key, { key: Key, reduce: true }>;
type Test2 = Test<'groupId'>
```

`Test2` ends up being a `number`, but the contrived `fn`

```
const fn = <O extends Options, K extends string = ''>(): {
  onChange: (val: ValueOfValueKey<O, K, ValueKey<K>>) => void
} => {
  return { onChange: (val) => {}};
}
```

ended up with the `(val: "this-other-branch" | "this-branch") => void` inference.

Basically, the issue was subtly leaving out information and so TypeScript was unable to put the pieces together.